# websocket with codeigniter and android

Tags: php, android, codeigniter, websocket

i have a web application developed in codeigniter php and an android app for event management what i want to do is that whenever admin on web create an event a notification should be generated and shown into android app so all the user with android app can receive that notification without any interrupt.

so any one have idea how i can achieve this feature??
i am thinking of using web socket but i dont have any idea about it in codeigniter and android so any kind of suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I would use the following components:

- ZeroMQ for passing the messages  http://zeromq.org
- Ratchet for web-socket server    http://socketo.me
- Autobahn for web-socke client    http://autobahn.ws/android/

I have no clue as to what you could use on the android side to subscribe to the web-service server.

The code is fairly simple, here is an example of something i use in my project.

Web-socket server:

**composer.json**

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "MyApp": "src"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "cboden/ratchet": "0.3.*",
        "react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*"
    }
}
```

**push-server.php**

```
<?php

require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
// I assume the codeigniter installation and this server 
// will be on the same host, hence 127.0.0.1
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:5555'); 
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onMessage'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8081, '0.0.0.0'); // Binding to 0.0.0.0 means remotes can connect
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
        new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
        new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
        $pusher
        )
        )
        ), $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

Then in codeigniter you can use the following to send messages:

```
$context = new ZMQContext();
$socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'pusher');
$zmq_srv = 'your.domain.com:5555';
$socket->connect("tcp://" . $zmq_srv);

$messageContent = array(
    'user' => 'username',
    'type' => 'success',
    'message' => 'Hi this is a test message.',
);

$socket->send(json_encode($messageContent));
```

I use this above to send messages to particular user, but if you make a new channel to which all your users are connected then all of them would receive a message.

My web based app uses http://autobahn.ws/js/ in the views to subscribe to the web-socket feeds. I see it has android implementation as well, but i've never tried that one: http://autobahn.ws/android/

This is the sample code from one of my views in case it is useful to you:

```
<script src="http://autobahn.s3.amazonaws.com/js/autobahn.min.js"></script>
<script>
        var conn = new ab.Session('ws://your.domain.com:8081',
                function () {
                    // Subscribe to the "username" channel
                    // For each user this would be their own channel to receive notifications
                    // for their own events, like successful file generation..
                    // file upload, etc...
                    conn.subscribe('username', function (topic, data) {
                         $.simplyToast(data.message, type = data.type, delay = 8000);
                    });
                    // Subscribe to "system" channel. 
                    //In my app all users are subscribed to this one to receive system-wide 
                    // notifications.
                    conn.subscribe('system', function (topic, data) {
                         $.simplyToast(data.message, type = data.type, delay = 8000);
                    });
                },
                function () {
                    console.warn('WebSocket connection closed');
                },
                {'skipSubprotocolCheck': true}
        );
    </script>
```